# @Batchsize annotation not working for OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have following classes and on annotating @BatchSize annotation it is not working and I am getting n+1 select query.

```
Class Shipment{
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = order.shipment, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
 orphanRemoval = true)
 @BatchSize(size=20)
 Set<Orders> orders = new Hashset(); <---- Batch size annotation not working 
 }
```

Order.class

```
class Order{
 @ToString.Exclude
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "item_fk")
 Item item;

 @ToString.Exclude
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "shipment_fk")
 Shipment shipment; }
```

Item.class

```
class Item{
 String id;
 String name;
}
```

What is mistake in implementation that i am getting n+1 queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to use `List<Orders>` instead of `Set<Orders>`.
2. Please note as it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-batch):

> However, although `@BatchSize` is better than running into an N+1 query issue, most of the time, a DTO projection or a `JOIN FETCH` is a much better alternative since it allows you to fetch all the required data with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Your N + 1 query issue is due to the fact that you do eager fetching of `Item` in `Order`. Change to LAZY there and you should be good to go.

Comment: tried with lazy too  but issue still exists

Comment: Please add the generated queries so that we can see what is actually happening.